# How to resolve dependency at runtime in Angular4

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

i am starting to learn dependency injection in angular4. suppose i have two service like this

**service a**

```
export class BigService {

  constructor() { }


  print(){
    alert('big service');
  }
}
```

**service b**

```
 export class SmallService {

      constructor() { }


      print(){
        alert('small service');
      }
    }
```

now, i want to resolve the dependency at run time, lets say i want to call the small service when the browser window size is < 1000px and big service when the browser window size is > 1000px

this is my component where i tried to resolve the dependency on clicking of a button

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-b',
  templateUrl: './parent-b.component.html',
 styles:[`
 <input type="button" value="submit" (click)='userButtonClick()'>
 `]
})
export class ParentBComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
  }


  userButtonClick(){
  this.useInjector();
  }


  useInjector(){
    const truthy=true;
    let injector=ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      {
        provide:'service',
        useFactory:()=>{
          if(truthy){
            return new SmallService();
          }else{
            return new BigService();
          }
        }
      }
      ])

      let _s=injector.get('service')
      _s.print();
  }


}
```

but i am not able to resolve it and i am getting an error like this

[image]

Comment: Have you used @Injectable in your service?

Comment: well i dont have any dependency in my service that is the reason i have not used it but using @injectables() also doesnt solve my problem

Comment: You could use a third service (as a facade) that gets the `BigService` and `SmallService` injected into it and determines which of the injected services to use when a method is called (depending on the width of the current browser). This service would be what is injected and used throughout your app.